# I used a custom view to preview my UIImagePicker preview, how can I extract the same region from the resulting image as was previewed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my view I have a `UIView` that I use to preview the camera. It's a lot smaller than the regular preview view (128x128). I initialise the `UIImagePickerController` like this:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

self.picker.view.frame = self.profilePictureView.frame;
```

I then use `[v addSubview:self.picker.view];` to show the camera's preview within my custom `UIVIew`. So far this works as intended, I see the part of the camera preview that overlaps my custom view in that view (essentially masking the preview with my custom view).
Now I'm trying to get what is displayed in my `UIView` into a `UIImage` (resulting in a 128x128 image). I tried using the delegation methods, but I only get the full size image from the camera there. I also tried taking a screenshot from the view but I got lost...

How can I create a `UIImage` with the exact same content as the view I use to render the camera preview, including size, offset and ratio?